# Modify PHP Search Script to Handle Multiple Entries For a Single Input

Tags: php, wordpress, search, forms

I need to modify a php search script so that it can handle multiple entries for a single field. The search engine is designed for a real estate website. The current search form allows users to search for houses by selecting a single neighborhood from a dropdown menu. Instead of a dropdown menu, I would like to use a list of checkboxes so that the the user can search for houses in multiple neighborhoods at one time. I have converted all of the dropdown menu items into checkboxes on the HTML side but the PHP script only searches for houses in the last checkbox selected. For example, if I selected: 'Dallas' 'Boston' 'New York' the search engine will only search for houses in New York.

Im new to PHP, so I am a little at a loss as to how to modify this script to handle the behavior I have described:

```
<?php

    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/extra_search_fields.php');

    //Add Widget for configurable search.
    add_action('plugins_loaded',array('DB_CustomSearch_Widget','init'));


    class DB_CustomSearch_Widget extends DB_Search_Widget {
        function DB_CustomSearch_Widget($params=array()){
            DB_CustomSearch_Widget::__construct($params);
        }
        function __construct($params=array()){
            $this->loadTranslations();
            parent::__construct(__('Custom Fields ','wp-custom-fields-search'),$params);
            add_action('admin_print_scripts', array(&$this,'print_admin_scripts'), 90);
            add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this,'plugin_menu'), 90);
            add_filter('the_content', array(&$this,'process_tag'),9);
            add_shortcode( 'wp-custom-fields-search', array(&$this,'process_shortcode') );
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
            if(version_compare("2.7",$GLOBALS['wp_version'])>0) wp_enqueue_script('dimensions');
        }
        function init(){
            global $CustomSearchFieldStatic;
            $CustomSearchFieldStatic['Object'] = new DB_CustomSearch_Widget();
            $CustomSearchFieldStatic['Object']->ensureUpToDate();
        }

        function currentVersion(){
            return "0.3.16";
        }

        function ensureUpToDate(){
            $version = $this->getConfig('version');
            $latest = $this->currentVersion();
            if($version<$latest) $this->upgrade($version,$latest);
        }

        function upgrade($current,$target){
            $options = $this->getConfig();
            if(version_compare($current,"0.3")<0){
                $config = $this->getDefaultConfig();
                $config['name'] = __('Default Preset','wp-custom-fields-search');
                $options['preset-default'] = $config;
            }
            $options['version']=$target;
            update_option($this->id,$options);
        }

        function getInputs($params = false,$visitedPresets=array()){
            if(is_array($params)){
                $id = $params['widget_id'];
            } else {
                $id = $params;
            }
            if($visitedPresets[$id]) return array();
            $visitedPresets[$id]=true;

            global $CustomSearchFieldStatic;
            if(!$CustomSearchFieldStatic['Inputs'][$id]){

                $config = $this->getConfig($id);
                $inputs = array();
                if($config['preset']) $inputs = $this->getInputs($config['preset'],$visitedPresets);
                $nonFields = $this->getNonInputFields();
                if($config)
                foreach($config as $k=>$v){
                    if(in_array($k,$nonFields)) continue;
                    if(!(class_exists($v['input']) && class_exists($v['comparison']) && class_exists($v['joiner']))) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $inputs[] =  new CustomSearchField($v);

                }
                foreach($inputs as $k=>$v){
                    $inputs[$k]->setIndex($k);
                }
                $CustomSearchFieldStatic['Inputs'][$id]=$inputs;
            }
            return $CustomSearchFieldStatic['Inputs'][$id];
        }
        function getTitle($params){
            $config = $this->getConfig($params['widget_id']);
            return $config['name'];
        }

        function form_processPost($post,$old){
            unset($post['###TEMPLATE_ID###']);
            if(!$post) $post=array('exists'=>1);
            return $post;
        }
        function getDefaultConfig(){
            return array('name'=>'Site Search', 
                1=>array(
                    'label'=>__('Key Words','wp-custom-fields-search'),
                    'input'=>'TextField',
                    'comparison'=>'WordsLikeComparison',
                    'joiner'=>'PostDataJoiner',
                    'name'=>'all'
                ),
                2=>array(
                    'label'=>__('Category','wp-custom-fields-search'),
                    'input'=>'DropDownField',
                    'comparison'=>'EqualComparison',
                    'joiner'=>'CategoryJoiner'
                ),
            );
        }
        function form_outputForm($values,$pref){
            $defaults=$this->getDefaultConfig();
            $prefId = preg_replace('/^.*\[([^]]*)\]$/','\\1',$pref);
            $this->form_existsInput($pref);
            $rand = rand();
?>
    <div id='config-template-<?php echo $prefId?>' style='display: none;'>
    <?php 
        $templateDefaults = $defaults[1];
        $templateDefaults['label'] = 'Field ###TEMPLATE_ID###';
        echo  $this->singleFieldHTML($pref,'###TEMPLATE_ID###',$templateDefaults);
    ?>
    </div>

<?php
            foreach($this->getClasses('input') as $class=>$desc) {
                if(class_exists($class))
                    $form = new $class();
                else $form = false;
                if(compat_method_exists($form,'getConfigForm')){
                    if($form = $form->getConfigForm($pref.'[###TEMPLATE_ID###]',array('name'=>'###TEMPLATE_NAME###'))){
?>
    <div id='config-input-templates-<?php echo $class?>-<?php echo $prefId?>' style='display: none;'>
        <?php echo $form?>
    </div>

<?php                   }
                }
            }
 ?>
    <div id='config-form-<?php echo $prefId?>'>
<?php
            if(!$values) $values = $defaults;
            $maxId=0;
            $presets = $this->getPresets();
            array_unshift($presets,__('NONE','wp-custom-fields-search'));
?>
        <div class='searchform-name-wrapper'><label for='<?php echo $prefId?>[name]'><?php echo __('Search Title','wp-custom-fields-search')?></label><input type='text' class='form-title-input' id='<?php echo $prefId?>[name]' name='<?php echo $pref?>[name]' value='<?php echo $values['name']?>'/></div>
        <div class='searchform-preset-wrapper'><label for='<?php echo $prefId?>[preset]'><?php echo __('Use Preset','wp-custom-fields-search')?></label>
<?php
            $dd = new AdminDropDown($pref."[preset]",$values['preset'],$presets);
            echo $dd->getInput()."</div>";
            $nonFields = $this->getNonInputFields();
            foreach($values as $id => $val){
                $maxId = max($id,$maxId);
                if(in_array($id,$nonFields)) continue;
                echo "<div id='config-form-$prefId-$id'>".$this->singleFieldHTML($pref,$id,$val)."</div>";
            }
?>
    </div>

    <br/><a href='#' onClick="return CustomSearch.get('<?php echo $prefId?>').add();"><?php echo __('Add Field','wp-custom-fields-search')?></a>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
            CustomSearch.create('<?php echo $prefId?>','<?php echo $maxId?>');
<?php
    foreach($this->getClasses('joiner') as $joinerClass=>$desc){
        if(compat_method_exists($joinerClass,'getSuggestedFields')){
            $options = eval("return $joinerClass::getSuggestedFields();");
            $str = '';
            foreach($options as $i=>$v){
                $k=$i;
                if(is_numeric($k)) $k=$v;
                $options[$i] = json_encode(array('id'=>$k,'name'=>$v));
            }
            $str = '['.join(',',$options).']';
            echo "CustomSearch.setOptionsFor('$joinerClass',".$str.");\n";
        }elseif(eval("return $joinerClass::needsField();")){
            echo "CustomSearch.setOptionsFor('$joinerClass',[]);\n";
        }
    }
?>
    </script>
<?php
        }

        function getNonInputFields(){
            return array('exists','name','preset','version');
        }
        function singleFieldHTML($pref,$id,$values){
            $prefId = preg_replace('/^.*\[([^]]*)\]$/','\\1',$pref);
            $pref = $pref."[$id]";
            $htmlId = $pref."[exists]";
            $output = "<input type='hidden' name='$htmlId' value='1'/>";
            $titles="<th>".__('Label','wp-custom-fields-search')."</th>";
            $inputs="<td><input type='text' name='$pref"."[label]' value='$values[label]' class='form-field-title'/></td><td><a href='#' onClick='return CustomSearch.get(\"$prefId\").toggleOptions(\"$id\");'>".__('Show/Hide Config','wp-custom-fields-search')."</a></td>";
            $output.="<table class='form-field-table'><tr>$titles</tr><tr>$inputs</tr></table>";
            $output.="<div id='form-field-advancedoptions-$prefId-$id' style='display: none'>";
            $inputs='';$titles='';
            $titles="<th>".__('Data Field','wp-custom-fields-search')."</th>";
            $inputs="<td><div id='form-field-dbname-$prefId-$id' class='form-field-title-div'><input type='text' name='$pref"."[name]' value='$values[name]' class='form-field-title'/></div></td>";
            $count=1;
            foreach(array('joiner'=>__('Data Type','wp-custom-fields-search'),'comparison'=>__('Compare','wp-custom-fields-search'),'input'=>__('Widget','wp-custom-fields-search')) as $k=>$v){
                $dd = new AdminDropDown($pref."[$k]",$values[$k],$this->getClasses($k),array('onChange'=>'CustomSearch.get("'.$prefId.'").updateOptions("'.$id.'","'.$k.'")','css_class'=>"wpcfs-$k"));
                $titles="<th>".$v."</th>".$titles;
                $inputs="<td>".$dd->getInput()."</td>".$inputs;
                if(++$count==2){
                    $output.="<table class='form-field-table form-class-$k'><tr>$titles</tr><tr>$inputs</tr></table>";
                    $count=0;
                    $inputs = $titles='';
                }
            }
            if($titles){
                $output.="<table class='form-field-table'><tr>$titles</tr><tr>$inputs</tr></table>";
                $inputs = $titles='';
            }
            $titles.="<th>".__('Numeric','wp-custom-fields-search')."</th><th>".__('Widget Config','wp-custom-fields-search')."</th>";
            $inputs.="<td><input type='checkbox' ".($values['numeric']?"checked='true'":"")." name='$pref"."[numeric]'/></td>";

            if(class_exists($widgetClass = $values['input'])){
                $widget = new $widgetClass();
                if(compat_method_exists($widget,'getConfigForm'))
                    $widgetConfig=$widget->getConfigForm($pref,$values);
            }


            $inputs.="<td><div id='$this->id"."-$prefId"."-$id"."-widget-config'>$widgetConfig</div></td>";
            $output.="<table class='form-field-table'><tr>$titles</tr><tr>$inputs</tr></table>";
            $output.="</div>";
            $output.="<a href='#' onClick=\"return CustomSearch.get('$prefId').remove('$id');\">Remove Field</a>";
            return "<div class='field-wrapper'>$output</div>";
        }

        function getRootURL(){
            return WP_CONTENT_URL .'/plugins/' .  dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '/';
        }
        function print_admin_scripts($params){
            $jsRoot = $this->getRootURL().'js';
            $cssRoot = $this->getRootURL().'css';
            $scripts = array('Class.js','CustomSearch.js','flexbox/jquery.flexbox.js');
            foreach($scripts as $file){
                echo "<script src='$jsRoot/$file' ></script>";
            }
            echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='$cssRoot/admin.css' >";
            echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='$jsRoot/flexbox/jquery.flexbox.css' >";
        }

        function getJoiners(){
            return $this->getClasses('joiner');
        }
        function getComparisons(){
            return $this->getClasses('comparison');
        }
        function getInputTypes(){
            return $this->getClasses('input');
        }
        function getClasses($type){
            global $CustomSearchFieldStatic;
            if(!$CustomSearchFieldStatic['Types']){
                $CustomSearchFieldStatic['Types'] = array(
                    "joiner"=>array(
                        "PostDataJoiner" =>__( "Post Field",'wp-custom-fields-search'),
                        "CustomFieldJoiner" =>__( "Custom Field",'wp-custom-fields-search'),
                        "CategoryJoiner" =>__( "Category",'wp-custom-fields-search'),
                        "TagJoiner" =>__( "Tag",'wp-custom-fields-search'),
                        "PostTypeJoiner" =>__( "Post Type",'wp-custom-fields-search'),
                    ),
                    "input"=>array(
                        "TextField" =>__( "Text Input",'wp-custom-fields-search'),
                        "DropDownField" =>__( "Drop Down",'wp-custom-fields-search'),
                        "RadioButtonField" =>__( "Radio Button",'wp-custom-fields-search'),
                        "HiddenField" =>__( "Hidden Constant",'wp-custom-fields-search'),
                    ),
                    "comparison"=>array(
                        "EqualComparison" =>__( "Equals",'wp-custom-fields-search'),
                        "LikeComparison" =>__( "Phrase In",'wp-custom-fields-search'),
                        "WordsLikeComparison" =>__( "Words In",'wp-custom-fields-search'),
                        "LessThanComparison" =>__( "Less Than",'wp-custom-fields-search'),
                        "MoreThanComparison" =>__( "More Than",'wp-custom-fields-search'),
                        "AtMostComparison" =>__( "At Most",'wp-custom-fields-search'),
                        "AtLeastComparison" =>__( "At Least",'wp-custom-fields-search'),
                        "RangeComparison" =>__( "Range",'wp-custom-fields-search'),
//TODO: Make this work...
//                      "NotEqualComparison" =>__( "Not Equal To",'wp-custom-fields-search'),
                    )
                );
                $CustomSearchFieldStatic['Types'] = apply_filters('custom_search_get_classes',$CustomSearchFieldStatic['Types']);
            }
            return $CustomSearchFieldStatic['Types'][$type];
        }
        function plugin_menu(){
            add_options_page('Form Presets','WP Custom Fields Search',8,__FILE__,array(&$this,'presets_form'));
        }
        function getPresets(){
            $presets = array();
            foreach(array_keys($config = $this->getConfig()) as $key){
                if(strpos($key,'preset-')===0) {
                    $presets[$key] = $key;
                    if($name = $config[$key]['name'])
                        $presets[$key]=$name;
                }
            }
            return $presets;
        }
        function presets_form(){
            $presets=$this->getPresets();
            if(!$preset = $_REQUEST['selected-preset']){
                $preset = 'preset-default';
            }
            if(!$presets[$preset]){
                $defaults = $this->getDefaultConfig();
                $options = $this->getConfig();
                $options[$preset] = $defaults;
                if($n = $_POST[$this->id][$preset]['name'])
                    $options[$preset]['name'] = $n;
                elseif($preset=='preset-default')
                    $options[$preset]['name'] = 'Default';
                else{
                    list($junk,$id) = explode("-",$preset);
                    $options[$preset]['name'] = 'New Preset '.$id;
                }
                update_option($this->id,$options);
                $presets[$preset] = $options[$preset]['name'];
            }
            if($_POST['delete']){
                check_admin_referer($this->id.'-editpreset-'.$preset);
                $options = $this->getConfig();
                unset($options[$preset]);
                unset($presets[$preset]);
                update_option($this->id,$options);
                list($preset,$name) = each($presets);
            }

            $index = 1;
            while($presets["preset-$index"]) $index++;
            $presets["preset-$index"] = __('New Preset','wp-custom-fields-search');

            $linkBase = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            $linkBase = preg_replace("/&?selected-preset=[^&]*(&|$)/",'',$linkBase);
            foreach($presets as $key=>$name){
                $config = $this->getConfig($key);
                if($config && $config['name']) $name=$config['name'];
                if(($n = $_POST[$this->id][$key]['name'])&&(!$_POST['delete']))
                    $name = $n;
                $presets[$key]=$name;
            }
            $plugin=&$this;
            ob_start();
            wp_nonce_field($this->id.'-editpreset-'.$preset);
            $hidden = ob_get_contents();
            $hidden.="<input type='hidden' name='selected-preset' value='$preset'>";
            $shouldSave = $_POST['selected-preset'] && !$_POST['delete'] && check_admin_referer($this->id.'-editpreset-'.$preset);
            ob_end_clean();
            include(dirname(__FILE__).'/templates/options.php');
        }
        function process_tag($content){
            $regex = '/\[\s*wp-custom-fields-search\s+(?:([^\]=]+(?:\s+.*)?))?\]/';
            return preg_replace_callback($regex, array(&$this, 'generate_from_tag'), $content);
        }
        function process_shortcode($atts,$content){
            return $this->generate_from_tag(array("",$atts['preset']));
        }
        function generate_from_tag($reMatches){
            global $CustomSearchFieldStatic;
            ob_start();

            $preset=$reMatches[1];
            if(!$preset) $preset = 'default';
            wp_custom_fields_search($preset);

            $form = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
            return $form;
        }
    }
    global $CustomSearchFieldStatic;
    $CustomSearchFieldStatic['Inputs'] = array();
    $CustomSearchFieldStatic['Types'] = array();

    class AdminDropDown extends DropDownField {
        function AdminDropDown($name,$value,$options,$params=array()){
            AdminDropDown::__construct($name,$value,$options,$params);
        }
        function __construct($name,$value,$options,$params=array()){
            $params['options'] = $options;
            $params['id'] = $params['name'];
            parent::__construct($params);
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->value = $value;
        }
        function getHTMLName(){
            return $this->name;
        }
        function getValue(){
            return $this->value;
        }
        function getInput(){
            return parent::getInput($this->name,null);
        }
    }

if (!function_exists('json_encode'))
{
  function json_encode($a=false)
  {
    if (is_null($a)) return 'null';
    if ($a === false) return 'false';
    if ($a === true) return 'true';
    if (is_scalar($a))
    {
      if (is_float($a))
      {
        // Always use "." for floats.
        return floatval(str_replace(",", ".", strval($a)));
      }

      if (is_string($a))
      {
        static $jsonReplaces = array(array("\\", "/", "\n", "\t", "\r", "\b", "\f", '"'), array('\\\\', '\\/', '\\n', '\\t', '\\r', '\\b', '\\f', '\"'));
        return '"' . str_replace($jsonReplaces[0], $jsonReplaces[1], $a) . '"';
      }
      else
        return $a;
    }
    $isList = true;
    for ($i = 0, reset($a); $i < count($a); $i++, next($a))
    {
      if (key($a) !== $i)
      {
        $isList = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    $result = array();
    if ($isList)
    {
      foreach ($a as $v) $result[] = json_encode($v);
      return '[' . join(',', $result) . ']';
    }
    else
    {
      foreach ($a as $k => $v) $result[] = json_encode($k).':'.json_encode($v);
      return '{' . join(',', $result) . '}';
    }
  }
}
function wp_custom_fields_search($presetName='default'){
    global $CustomSearchFieldStatic;
    if(strpos($presetName,'preset-')!==0) $presetName="preset-$presetName";
    $CustomSearchFieldStatic['Object']->renderWidget(array('widget_id'=>$presetName,'noTitle'=>true),array('number'=>$presetName));
}
function compat_method_exists($class,$method){
    return method_exists($class,$method) || in_array(strtolower($method),get_class_methods($class));
}
```

Comment: Woah... that's a lot of code you pasted, and a lot of it is unrelated to your problem. Is it possible to narrow it down to the html of the form and just the parts of the script that process the form? Also I noticed wp_custom_fields_search(), does this have somthing to do with wordpress? If so perhaps you should add a wordpress tag to the question.

Comment: Thats the problem, Im not a PHP developer so Im not real sure which parts of this code are related to the function that I need to modify to make this work the way I want.

Comment: Oh yeah and it is a wordpress plugin specifically this one:
http://www.don-benjamin.co.uk/projects/foss/wp-plugins/wp-custom-fields-search-03/#post-41
I will add a tag....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your needs would require a non-trivial expansion of the plugin with a new input class. You should probably contact the plugin's developer(s) to request the feature or search for another plugin that satisfies your needs.

If you really want to take a crack at it yourself, I suggest putting the plugin aside and rolling your own search form and pushing that input into `WP_query()`.  Here are a few links to get you started on that:

[Modifying A Search Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page#Preserving_Search_Page_Results_and_Pagination)

[Working with `WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Interacting_with_WP_Query)

[Query argument guide](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts)